# How to POST a JSON to a remote url using Coldfusion 9?

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion

We are trying to communicate with a remote API which requires JSON formatted data. We tried to submit this using JQuery as follows, but were getting SOP errors:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    url:  "https://api.e2ma.net/123/members/add",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data:
     {
       "fields": {
       "name_first": "Name"
     },
     "email": "email@domain.com"
    }
  });
</script>
```

Unfortunately, their API **does not** support **JSONP**.

How can we post this JSON data to their remote API directly from within Coldfusion 9?

Also, what do we need to do to **parse the response** from their API?

Here is a link to the docs:  http://myemma.com/api-docs/

And here is snippet of a simple add new member call from those docs:

```
import_single_member(account_id)
POST /#account_id/members/add

Adds or updates an audience member

Parameters: 

  email (string) – Email address of member to add or update
  fields (dictionary) – Names and values of user-defined fields to update
  group_ids (integer) – Optional. Add imported members to this list of groups.
  signup_form_id – Optional. Indicate that this member used a particular signup form.

Returns:    
  The member_id of the new or updated member, and whether the member was added or an  existing member was updated

Example:

POST /123/members/add
{
  "fields": {
    "first_name": "Benjamin"
  }, 
  "email": "benjamin@myemma.com"
}

{
  "added": true, 
  "member_id": 1024
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You want to setup a proxy on your server that grabs the remote JSON data, you then call your local proxy with JavaScript, it gets the remote data, and returns it to the browser. jQuery offers the ability to decode JSON with `$.parseJSON()`. Your proxy just acts as an intermediary between your JavaScript and the remote service to avoid Cross-Domain-Policy issues.

Comment: Isn't there a way to skip JQuery/JS altogether (and thereby the need for a proxy) by posting this JSON data directly from within CF?

Comment: Sure, grab the remote data with CF and then just output it in whatever format you want. I only mentioned the JavaScript portion because you tagged the question with jQuery. Without JavaScript you will have to reload the whole page to get new data, I guess is the down-side to only using a server-side script.

Comment: I believe that `cfhttp` will do that for you. You can send a `post` or `get` request to the remote server and receive it's response. I've only edited someone else's code that does this so I'm no expert but it's made quite easy in CF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to build a proxy since you can't POST to another server from JavaScript. Your JS code should look something like:

```
$.ajax({
url:  "https://yourserver/proxy.cfm",
dataType: 'json',
type: 'POST',
data:
 "name_first": "Name",
 "email": "email@domain.com"
}
});
```

And your ColdFusion code should look something like this:

```
<cfhttp url="https://api.e2ma.net/123/members/add" method="post" username="username" password="password">
    <cfhttpparam name="email" value="#form.email#">
    <cfhttpparam name="fields" value='{"name_first":"#form.name_first#"}'>
</cfhhtp>
```

I'm not sure if the fields will be in the format needed but ti should be pretty close.

You can also return whatever you get back to JavaScript like this after you do the post:

```
<cfoutput>#cfhttp.filecontent#<cfoutput>
```

Comment: Okay, so we need to use cfhttp. That being the case, to help make this as modular as possible, can we specify different methods in ajax call which would point to different cfhttp calls within proxy.cfm? One for add, one for delete, etc.?

Comment: Sure. To keep it simple you could use cfswitch and have a case for each method you need to use. It is also possible you could make the ColdFusion code generic enough that it would just take whatever you need to pass in and transfer it on to the other server. However without knowledge of the other server's API and what types of fields and collections it expects I wouldn't want to start there.